# Getting errors when i change build target back to 2.3.3

Tags: android, themes

Getting errors in style.xml when i change build target to 2.3.3, I think i need to change the theme from holo to something but i don't know any theme names

Here the line where the errors are

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Comment: You can find the themes here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml Got the reference from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holo theme is not supported for old android versions. A quick option could be this

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    ...
</style>
```

[More Themes Info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Hi thanks, i'm still getting errors when i added that do i need to do somtehing else

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I just update the code of my answer.

Comment: I'm getting lots of errors R.java file is after disappearing so mainly r cannot be resolved but still getting error on this line in style, do i need to add this to manifest too

Comment: Then maybe you have another problem that is causing that the R class is not generated. As a suggestion first comment the lines with errors and ensure that the R class is generated then you can try again the style creation.

Comment: Hi thanks for help, when I changed build target back to 4.2 errors went away and with the theme you said, my edit text are the same in the version i tried so far and this is what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using advanced features like action bar..etc there is one library project called SherlocActionBar you can try with this